# Delete post from a list of posts via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Say I'm making a webpage with a list of users' posts (eg. Twitter feed) and the user wants to delete a post from it. The list is dynamically generated using PHP and a MySQL DB. I also have a delete.php which takes an ID as an input via a POST request and deletes the entry with the ID. I know I can send a post request via jquery, by having the user click on a delete icon, placed besides every post on the feed. How should I structure the HTML so that I can figure out which post to delete? Should I include an ID to the outputted HTML? Or is there something else? Please help!

Comment: Yes. There are numerous ways to do that, forms with hidden fields, data attributes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a data-id="123" attribute to the delete button. You can access that value via jquery and include in as a POST var.

Something like:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/ajaxurl.php';
    $.post(url, {id: id}, function(response) {
        alert('Post deleted');
    });
});
```